# Cakephp 3 - what's the right association type for Players/Matches relation?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my cakephp3 app I have a Players table, and a Matches table that records every match done between two players. The structure of my table matches is:

- id
- created <-- datetime
- winner_id <-- id of player who won the match.
- loser_id <-- id of player who lost the match.

I have defined associations between Players and Matches as follow:

```
// in src/Model/Table/PlayersTable.php
$this->hasMany('Victories', [
    'className' => 'Matches',
    'foreignKey' => 'winner_id'
]);
$this->hasMany('Losses', [
    'className' => 'Matches',
    'foreignKey' => 'loser_id'
]);
```

When I want to retrieve a player with all his matches, I do:

```
// in src/Controller/PlayersController.php
$player = $this->Players->findById($user_id)->contain(['Victories', 'Losses'])->first();
```

But that's not very convenient because to get all the player's matches in one place, I then have to merge `$player->victories` and `$player->losses`. 
Plus I can't easily perform simple requests like "get a player with its 50 last matches".

So I feel like my db schema is not ideal and that i could be improved. But I don't really see how. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right schema would be to remove the `winner_id` and `loser_id` out of matches and put them into another table that could be called `contenders`

Table contenders:

```
* match_id
* player_id
* has_won (boolean)
```

And You associate your table Matches to Contenders using a `hasMany`:

```
$this->hasMany('Contenders');
```

Now you can also associate Matchers to Players using a `belongsToMany` association:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Players', ['through' => 'Contenders']);
```

You can also associate the Players table to have Victories and Losses:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Victories', [
    'className' => 'Matches',
    'through' => 'Contenders'
    'conditions' => ['Contenders.has_won' => true]
]);

$this->belongsToMany('Losses', [
    'className' => 'Matches',
    'through' => 'Contenders'
    'conditions' => ['Contenders.has_won' => false]
]);
```

Finally you can also know all the matches for a player by adding another `belognsToMany`:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Matches');
```